# loadScript fails in Community: Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 503 (Service Unavailable)

Tags: javascript, lightning-web-components, community, static-resources

I am loading a JS file in a LWC with:

```
import { loadScript } from "lightning/platformResourceLoader";

connectedCallback() {
    loadScript(this, "/resource/simpleTest")
      .then(() => {
        console.log("file loaded");
      })
      .catch(e => {
        console.log("error: ", e);
      });
}
```

On Community I get:
"Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 503 (Service Unavailable)" and when I click on the url on the right I arrive on a page saying that "https://my-domain.cs189.force.com/digital is closed for maintenance...".
When testing outside Community it is working fine.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned [here](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning-platform-resource-loader/documentation), I don't think `lightning/platformResourceLoader` is supported for communities yet (*or at the least not fully supported*).